# TinyCsvParser not returning any results

Tags: c#, .net, csv, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently trying to use `TinyCsvParser` to parse a file and am getting 0 results returned despite my test content having plenty of entries. Code is below:

Mapping class:

```
public class TransactionCsvMapping : CsvMapping<TransactionDto>
{
    public TransactionCsvMapping()
    : base()
    {
        MapProperty(0, x => x.OccurenceDate);
        MapProperty(1, x => x.Name);
        MapProperty(4, x => x.Amount);
    }
}
```

The model class I am trying to create a list of from the CSV rows:

```
public class TransactionDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public DateTime OccurenceDate { get; set; }
}
```

Parsing the CSV file:

```
CsvParserOptions csvParserOptions = new CsvParserOptions(true, ',');
CsvReaderOptions csvReaderOptions = new CsvReaderOptions(new[] { Environment.NewLine });
TransactionCsvMapping csvMapper = new TransactionCsvMapping();
CsvParser<TransactionDto> csvParser = new CsvParser<TransactionDto>(csvParserOptions, csvMapper);

var result = csvParser
    .ReadFromString(csvReaderOptions, fileContents)
    .ToList(); //results is empty here!
```

and here is the contents of `fileContents` at the time of parsing:

```
"Date","Transaction","Name","Memo","Amount"
"9/7/2016","DEBIT","DEBIT PURCHASE","Food Yummy","-4.8000"
"9/7/2016","DEBIT","DEBIT PURCHASE","Gas Blah","-28.0000"
```

where the literal string is:

```
"\"Date\",\"Transaction\",\"Name\",\"Memo\",\"Amount\"\n\"9/7/2016\",\"DEBIT\",\"DEBIT PURCHASE\",\"Food Yummy\",\"-4.8000\"\n\"9/7/2016\",\"DEBIT\",\"DEBIT PURCHASE\",\"Gas Blah\",\"-28.0000\"\n\n"
```

Why am I not getting any results here? How can I overcome this?

Comment: iSN'T NAME 2? :        MapProperty(2, x => x.Name)

Comment: yes- this was an error from me editing/scrubbing the transaction file before posting here and doesn't matter in the context of this post. but you are indeed correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am succesfully getting results by using your code.

[image]

use `\r\n` instead of `\n` as Newline  or declare your newline operator with `\n`

```
new CsvReaderOptions(new[] { "\n" });
```

Comment: yep `Environment.NewLine` was my problem!